# bzr How to create a commit hook?

Tags: python, bazaar, bazaar-plugins

I am trying to make my first commit hook and it is not working.
I got the idea from here http://doc.bazaar.canonical.com/beta/en/user-guide/hooks.html

What I am trying todo is to start by making my own custom commit message.  but this does not work. please can you help?

I made a python file called `commit_hook.py`

```
from bzrlib import branch


def my_commit_hook(push_result):
    print "I made this and the new revno is %d" % commit_result.new_revno


branch.Branch.hooks.install_named_hook('post_commit', post_commit_hook,
                                 'My post_commit hook')
```

I put the file commit_hook.py in my .bzr hidden folder in my repository. I made the plugins directory? is that correct?

```
.bzr/
├── 
├── branch-format
├── branch-lock
├── plugins
│   └── commit_hook.py
├── README
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Per the docs](http://doc.bazaar.canonical.com/beta/en/user-reference/hooks-help.html#post-commit):

> post_commit is called with (local, master, old_revno, old_revid,
>   new_revno, new_revid).

Therefore,

```
def my_commit_hook(local, master, old_revno, old_revid, 
                   new_revno, new_revid):
```

Also, `post_commit_hook` should be `my_commit_hook`:

```
branch.Branch.hooks.install_named_hook('post_commit', 
                                       my_commit_hook,
                                       'My post_commit hook')
```

Comment: Hi - do have an example as i tried this and I am not seeing my message when I commit. I am not using a server all I am doing is committing to a repository on my local kubuntu laptop

Comment: I confess I'm just going by the docs; I don't use bzr. [According to this](http://ifdeflinux.blogspot.com/2012/07/a-bazaar-pre-commit-hook-to-look-for.html), the plugins should be placed in `~/.bazaar/plugins`. The plugin directory can also be specified by defining [BZR_PLUGIN_PATH](http://doc.bazaar.canonical.com/beta/en/user-reference/configuration-help.html#bzr-plugin-path).

Comment: Thanks I'll check it out an let you know. Thanks so much for the help

Comment: unindent does not match any outer indentation level  - do you know what this error means?

Comment: Thanks I see that python relies on specific indentation. I got it to work. Thanks for your help